# Phonegap iOS Push Notifications example

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I am creating mobile App for Android and iOS devices, that will receive Push Notifications. 
I have successfully implemented Google GCM by using phonegap PushPlugin, and notifications are working on Android devices, and now I am little bit stuck to develop the same for iOS.

Is there some goode example (without using any 3rd party services), where I can take guidence how it can be done for iOS, using the same PushPlugin?

Comment: Check this out http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/push-notifications/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some good tutorial i have been following. It will help you too.

1. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/
2. https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial
3. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html

Above references do not use external libraries or 3rd party services.

Regards.